# Psycopg2 installation error using pip

Tags: python

I want to install psycopg2.I am using mavericks 10.9.2.I tried

```
sudo pip install psycopg2
```

But i got error like this::

```
 clang: error: unknown argument: '-mno-fused-madd' [-Wunused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future]
    clang: note: this will be a hard error (cannot be downgraded to a warning) in the future
    error: command 'cc' failed with exit status 1

    ----------------------------------------
Command "/usr/bin/python -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/private/tmp/pip-build-nLGzhp/psycopg2/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-xFWboX-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /private/tmp/pip-build-nLGzhp/psycopg2
```

How can rectify this please help me!!Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The Xcode version that is shipped with OS X Mavericks doesn't allow to have unknown parameters passed, and that's why you are getting this error.

This can happen also with other Python packages that require to compile C extensions (not just psycopg2).

A workaround is to tell the compiler to behave like it used to using the following environment variable:

```
sudo ARCHFLAGS=-Wno-error=unused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future pip install psycopg2
```

ps. This will work now, but in the future using this option may be removed.